# Raspberry Pi 2: Unable to download .NET Core 2 Runtime

Tags: raspberry-pi, .net-core, arm

I have found several sites showing how to install the .NET Core 2 runtime on a Raspberry Pi, but I'm having problems getting the runtime to download.

```
https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Runtime/release/2.0.0/dotnet-runtime-latest-linux-arm.tar.gz
```

fails with a "resource not found" error, and

```
curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Runtime/release/2.0.0/dotnet-runtime-latest-linux-arm.tar.gz
```

succeeds but gets a file that is only 223 bytes, which I cannot believe is right.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know .net core 2.0 does not support Linux ARM distros like raspbian. This changed with the release of .net core 2.1:

```
.NET Core is now supported on Linux ARM32 distros, like Raspbian and Ubuntu!
```

[scott hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingRunningAndTestingNETCoreAndASPNETCore21InDockerOnARaspberryPiARM32.aspx)

Here you can find the .net core 2.1 runtimes for linux ARM32 distros: [github.com](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.1.0-download.md)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks @MUG4N.